# Connecting to connectionString in app.config

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, ms-access, database-connection

I have my connection string stored in App.Config

```
<connectionStrings>
 <clear />
 <add name="CTaC_Information_System.Properties.Settings.CIS_beConn"
     connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=&quot;\\server\file\CIS Data\Database\CIS_be.accdb&quote;;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123" 
     providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

Then when I go to my main.xaml.cs I type in the following:

```
string cisconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTaC_Information_System.Properties.Settings.CIS_beConn"].ConnectionString;`
```

I found that answer on Stack Overflow when searching, but some were say to put `var` but when I typed `var` it wouldn't recognize it so I went with the `string` method.

When I go to type `cisconn.Open();` the option isn't there. I am referencing `System.Configuartion;`,`System.Data.Sql;` `System.Data.SqlClient;` and `System.Data.OleDb;`.

Can someone show / tell me how I can connect to the database from c#? I'm trying to test the connection when my application runs but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I don't think you should be using &quot (or &quote, which is incorrect) in the string. should just be "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\server\file\CIS Data\Database\CIS_be.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database; Password=123" plus looks like you missed a semi-colon before the Password field.

Comment: That part of code was created by Visual Studio when I added the connection to the db - I didn't manually enter that. Although I may have missed typed a little when I was writing it in the question. That's why I can't figure out why I just can't do `cisconn.Open();`

Comment: Oh! Ha, yeah I missed that. The connection string is just a connection string, you still need to use an `OleDbConnection` to create it, like `OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cisconn);` then you can do `conn.Open()`

Comment: That's what I thought too but when I did that an error came up under cisconn stating this: `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property 'CTaC_Information_System.StartMenu.cisconn'` I'm lost as to what to do.

Comment: Thats a completely different string than what you have in the connection string, so that error has to be coming from somewhere else, but I can't tell where unless you post the code (edit your question).

Comment: I think I figured it out, you have the OleDbConnection as a field in the class, don't do that, use it then destroy it when  you are done, I edited my answer to show how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string is just a string, its meant to be used in your connection, so you should do:

```
public void DoSomeDatabaseOp()
{
    string cisconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTaC_Information_System.Properties.Settings.CIS_beConn"].ConnectionString;

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cisconn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        //Create your commands or do your SQL here.
    }
}
```

You should create/destroy the connection inside the method you are using it in. Don't keep a reference to it in the root of the class object. This keeps the connections clean and open if you aren't doing database operations.

If you really wanted to though, you could do this:

```
class MyClass
{
    OleDbConnection _rootConn;
    string _connStr;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _connStr = string cisconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTaC_Information_System.Properties.Settings.CIS_beConn"].ConnectionString;
        _rootConn = new OleDbConnection(_connStr);
    }

    public void DoSomeDatabaseOp()
    {
        //Use _rootConn here
    }
}
```

BUT **the class should implement IDisposable so that it can dispose of the connection properly!** How to implement IDisposable is beyond the scope of the answer, but look up how to implement it properly.

Comment: Didn't work due to this error:
`A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property 'CTaC_Information_System.StartMenu.cisconn'`

Comment: I edited the answer, you shouldn't use the OleDbConnection as a field in the class, if you do then it has to be initialized in a different way.

Comment: That worked. The problem I had was I had it under the `public partial class` so i moved it to the `private void` and bam it worked! Thank you for your help!

Comment: I modified the answer just to show how it could be done if you really wanted it under the root of the class.

Comment: Could I house the connection string and this in seperate class then access it through calling said class?

Comment: Example:  `dbClass.conn.Open();` that way on each form I don't have to retype the connection string and what not?

Comment: I would not recommend it because the OleDbConnection needs to be properly disposed and if you are creating it in one place and using it in another its easy to lose track and end up with memory leaks or connection pooling problems. But it is feasible to add a method inside your class that creates the connection, just remember to dispose of it when you are done.

Comment: That problem is why its best to use the `using` structure I posted in the first example, it ensures the connection is closed and disposed properly, even if there is an exception inside using statement and the method exits prematurely.